# How to make powershell shows list of suggestion after press tab?

Tags: powershell

In my computer at my company, when I press tab after typing something in powershell, it will show a list of suggestion and I can choose item in the list by using arrows key.
For example, this is the result when I type "fin" then press tab :

[image]

How to config powershell to show that list? I try to copy the powershell profile to my laptop and import neccessary module but it doesn't work like the picture (the shell only show the first thing match what I type, for the above example, it show the `Find-Command` when I type `fin` and press tab,but not the list)

Here is the profile :

```
function Test-Administrator {
    $user = [Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent();
    (New-Object Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal $user).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltinRole]::Administrator)
}

Import-Module posh-git
Import-Module oh-my-posh
Set-Theme Sorin

Import-Module Get-ChildItemColor

Set-Alias l Get-ChildItemColor -option AllScope
Set-Alias ls Get-ChildItemColorFormatWide -option AllScope

function cddash {
    if ($args[0] -eq '-') {
        $pwd = $OLDPWD;
    } else {
        $pwd = $args[0];
    }
    $tmp = pwd;

    if ($pwd) {
        Set-Location $pwd;
    }
    Set-Variable -Name OLDPWD -Value $tmp -Scope global;
}

Set-Alias -Name cd -value cddash -Option AllScope


# Chocolatey profile
$ChocolateyProfile = "$env:ChocolateyInstall\helpers\chocolateyProfile.psm1"
if (Test-Path($ChocolateyProfile)) {
   Import-Module "$ChocolateyProfile"
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're running in that screenshot isn't just PowerShell. It's ConEmu. So you're probably running ConEmu with the Posh-Git and oh-my-posh and PsReadline modules.

Psreadline provides the menu capability that you're talking about.

Once all the pre-requisites are met and PsReadLine is installed you can modify the key handler if you want so the menu option is assigned to tab. By default it's assigned to Ctrl + Space.

To bind it to tab:

```
import-module PsReadLine
Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler -Key Tab -Function MenuComplete
```

Answer (score 0):

If u have installed [neo vim](https://neovim.io/) in powershell

Just run `nvim $PROFILE` and then import module to set key tab function MenuComplete (recommended) or Complete

> `Import-Module PSReadline Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler -Key Tab -Function MenuComplete`

or

> `Import-Module PSReadline Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler -Key Tab -Function Complete`